# parsing calculation with PEG.js

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am trying to use the peg.js library to parse math expressions.
I put in [online peg.js](http://pegjs.org/online) the following grammar:

```
start
    = any

additive
    = left:primary "+" right:any { return left + right; }

multiplicative
    = left:primary "*" right:any { return left * right; }

any
    = multiplicative
    / additive
    / primary

primary
    = float
    / integer
    / "(" any:any ")" { return any; }
    / "" { return 0; }

float "float"
    = left:[0-9]+ "." right:[0-9]+ { return parseFloat(left.join("") + "." +   right.join("")); }

integer "integer"
     = digits:[0-9]+ { return parseInt(digits.join(""), 10); }
```

But when I try to calculate:
    `3*5+1` I get `18`

Comment: You've made a right-associative grammar and you've made multiplication and addition have the same precedence.

Comment: How do I make proper operator precedence?

Comment: You need another non-terminal "layer" so that multiplications are parsed as groups at a lower level than addition operands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the code below is what you're after.

The trick is having your weakest operator (+) have a rule which references a multiplication rule so that the addition cannot happen until multiplication has matched, which in turn cannot happen until primary expressions have matched.

```
start
    = any

any
    = additive

additive
    = left:multiplicative "+" right:additive { return left + right; }
    / multiplicative

multiplicative
    = left:primary "*" right:multiplicative { return left * right; }
    / primary


primary
    = float
    / integer
    / "(" any:any ")" { return any; }
    / "" { return 0; }

float "float"
    = left:[0-9]+ "." right:[0-9]+ { return parseFloat(left.join("") + "." +   right.join("")); }

integer "integer"
     = digits:[0-9]+ { return parseInt(digits.join(""), 10); }
```