# Pegjs Expected [0-9.] or end of input but "a" found

Tags: javascript, regex, pegjs

I want to handle `string starts with number` using pegjs. When I input with **1abcd** it throws `Expected [0-9.] or end of input but "a" found.`. The expected output is `{ item: '1abcd', case: '=' }`. What changes do I need?

```js
var parser = peg.generate(`
  start
    = number:NUMBER  { return { case: "=", item: number } } 
    / string:STRING  { return { case: "=", item: string.join("") } }

    NUMBER
    = number:[0-9\.]+ { return parseFloat(number.join("")); }
    / number:[0-9]+   { return parseInt(number.join(""), 10); }

    STRING = string:[^*]+ { return string; }
`);

console.log(parser.parse("123"))
console.log(parser.parse("123.45"))
console.log(parser.parse("abcd"))
console.log(parser.parse("abcd-efgh"))
console.log(parser.parse("1abcd"))
```

The output as follows:

```
{case: "=", item: 123}
{case: "=", item: 123.45}
{case: "=", item: "abcd"}
{case: "=", item: "abcd-efgh"}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-testing-sandbox-forked-5vekz?file=/src/index.js

Comment: The parsing of floats is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435500/parsing-calculation-with-peg-js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `NUMBER` matches the first character, you'll want to use a negative lookahead for `STRING` before returning a successful match. That way, if a `STRING` character is encountered, the `NUMBER` rule will fail and the second alternation of `start` will be used.

Here's an example, although as @thinkgruen has written, you'll probably want to try to parse floats less loosely as well.

```
start
    = number:NUMBER  { return { case: "=", item: number } } 
    / string:STRING  { return { case: "=", item: string.join("") } }

NUMBER
    = number:[0-9\.]+ (!STRING) { return parseFloat(number.join("")); }
    / number:[0-9]+   (!STRING) { return parseInt(number.join(""), 10); }

STRING = string:[^*]+ { return string; }
```